# CNTK Python API: evaluating hidden layers / multiple outputs

Tags: python, cntk

What are the recommendations for creating, saving, loading and evaluating models with multiple outputs in CNTK Python APIs? (I'm using CNTK 2.0 RC1)

When I define a network in run-time, I can evaluate any layer of the network easily, by passing a minibatch dictionary to the *eval* function.

However, after I save the model and load it again, I can evaluate only the output node by providing the inputs (and I don't know how to define multiple outputs in Python API). I can access any layer by using the *find_all_by_name* method, but when I try to evaluate hidden layers using the *eval* method, it expects me to provide the **layer's immediate input**, rather than relevant network's inputs:

```
ValueError: No value specified for input Variable 'Output('Block1958_Output_0', [#], [1024 x 200])' of Function 'Dense: Output('Block1958_Output_0', [#], [1024
x 200]) -> Output('conversation_vector', [#], [100])'.
```

I only found the following documentation on the topic, which applies to Brainscript: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Evaluate-Hidden-Layers -- I couldn't find anything specific to Python API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model.outputs[0] is a variable, you can go to its function by model.outputs[0].owner, or as_composite(model.outputs[0].owner) if the owner is a primitive function (which only shows the immediate inputs, vs. composite function that shows the root input variables for mapping)

So try this:

```
as_composite(model.outputs[0].owner).eval(...)
```

Comment: Preparing the last layer of the model using `cntk.combine` before saving it (per Zhou's suggestion in another post) and then using `as_composite(model.outputs[0].owner).eval(...)` after loading the model solved my problem - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After getting all layers you want, you can use Combine() to create a new Function, then call eval on the new Function. It works in C++, though I have not tried it in Python.

https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html?highlight=combine#cntk.ops.combine